# Angular 2 schema forms

Tags: forms, angular, schema, styling

I started to write Angular 2 application. I use there angular2 schema forms. It generates me bootstrap-like form well, however I'm not able to style it in any manner.

Component where I use schema forms body

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '../../shared/HttpClient.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'stylists-section',
  templateUrl: './stylists-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stylists-section.component.scss'],
})
export class StylistsSectionComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() quantity: number;
  @Input() col: string;
  @Input() query: string;
  @Input() title: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('data/Users', {'isStylist': true})
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.stylists = response;
      }, err => {
        console.error('our error: ', err);
      })
  }
```

I tried to style it through this scss file. What I do wrong?

Comment: What is "this css file"? What is the expected and actual behaivor?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is common sass file. I am able to style form which is parent of <schema-form> element. However I can't style any input and label element, which are rendered by this plugin

Comment: I had the same problem. Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`to the component. That makes the css global. You probably don’t want the css global but it only worked that way for me.